# Where can I build my house on Mercury so that I can see double sunsets (and sunrises)? Can I do it near the poles where it's cooler?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, mercury, orbital-resonance

CNN'S [Mercury mission flies by closest planet to the sun for the first time](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/10/01/world/bepicolombo-first-mercury-flyby-scn/index.html) says at the end:

> Mercury's unusual rotation and oval-shaped orbit around the sun (sic) means our star **seems to quickly rise, set and rise again on some parts of the planet**, and a similar phenomenon occurs at sunset.

When I build my dream home on Mercury, *I want that!* I want to see this rise-set-rise, set-rise-set *every single day!* :-)

But I also don't want my place to get too hot during the day, so I'd like to live closer to the poles where I can step outside without my boots quickly melting.

**Question:** Where can I build my house on Mercury so that I can see double sunsets (and sunrises)? Can I do it near the poles where it's cooler?

Is there a map? Or some equations based on latitude and longitude that define the areas where this happen? Is the rise-set-rise area exactly the same as the set-rise-set area?

Comment: a cool place is not a problem, it's -330℃ at night time

Comment: @WalidSiddik I'll have to "dress warm" to go outside at night, agreed. A house can use thermal storage and insulation to fight both hot and cold, that part is symmetric. It's also true that while many materials soften and melt and become useless when too hot, other materials become brittle and undergo phase transitions when too cold as well. So rather than saying the poles are desirable because they don't get too hot, I should say that they may present less extreme swings in temperature.

Comment: You can use [this 3D map](https://www.melowntech.com/mercury/?pos=obj,-88.752972,73.623888,fix,-1749.98,-10.81,-90.00,0.00,3312278.25,55.00) to find a perfect place for your dream home

Comment: @WalidSiddik I love it!

Comment: if you found out one don't forget to invite us ;)

Comment: @WalidSiddik -330C?  So, 57 below absolute zero.

Comment: if anyone want to know more about mercury's weather: [report of national weather service](https://www.weather.gov/fsd/mercury) (yeah I know)

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at Stellarium (if we trust its accuracy) suggests longitudes ~90 east and west (Edit: it seems that each of these corridors get to enjoy both double sunrise and sunsets, not only one or another!).

Yes, you can experience that effect near the poles, but take into account the local topography, as this is a timid effect we're talking about, and the sun being so close to the horizon could be covered by mountains and crater rims.

PS: I want to live on Mercury too, I'm moving with you!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I can't understand what all the images are meant to convey. Why are some areas in color and some monochrome? Does 88° east and west only apply to the equator, or does it extend along straight lines of longitude to each pole, or is there some cutoff at high latitudes?

Comment: sorry I should've explained a bit more, these are thermal maps, warmer colours are hotter, monochrome on the top map is unmapped areas, but on the lower map shows you the north pole. as you can see there are wide corridors (centered around 90 degrees W and E) where local noon happens at aphelion, so the temperatures are milder than on the regions it happens at perihelion(0 and 180). This is why Caloris (189 W) was called that, (latin for heat).

Comment: and yes, the cooler corridors extend all the way to the poles, if you look at the second pic on the lower map, the greener areas are aligned to 90 degrees east and west. The double sunrises would also happen there, but it'd be less dramatic than on lower latitudes.